# Filter MySQL timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm new and would appreciate help!! Need to remove rows if one or more "ID" is missing a timestamp. For example in the table below ID = 10 does not have a value for IRIG_Time = 2014-05-15 09:05:00.000, thus I need to remove all IRIG_Time rows for that timestamp. I'm using the following query to pull data (thanks to Barmar for the help so far!).

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
SELECT * 
FROM originaltable  Where IRIG_Time between  '2014/05/15 09:05' and '2014/05/15 09:35';
DELETE t.* FROM Table1 AS t
JOIN (
SELECT IRIG_Time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY IRIG_Time
HAVING COUNT(*) != 5
) AS t1 ON t.IRIG_TIME = t1.IRIG_TIME;
select * from Table1; 


IRIG_Time                   ID      MagnitudeA
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     5       730406000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     15      742456000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     20      731190000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.000     25      748572000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.033     5       730343000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.033     10      755865000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.033     15      742347000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.033     20      731168000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.033     25      748574000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.067     5       730420000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.067     10      755767000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.067     15      742310000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.067     20      731176000
2014-05-15 09:05:00.067     25      748524000
```

When using the above code I get Error Code: 1175 You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

Comment: Barmar,thanks for the help editing!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t.* FROM table AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT IRIG_Time
    FROM table
    GROUP BY IRIG_Time
    HAVING COUNT(*) != (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table)
    ) AS t1 ON t.IRIG_TIME = t1.IRIG_TIME
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1700/2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Barmar! I had to modify the "Safe Updates" preference, but the following script works!

```
Drop table Table1;
CREATE TABLE Table1
SELECT IRIG_Time, ID, MagnitudeA FROM originaltable 
Where IRIG_Time between '2014-05-25 13:00' and '2014-05-25 14:00' order by IRIG_Time;

DELETE t.* FROM Table1 AS t
JOIN (
SELECT IRIG_Time, ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY IRIG_Time
HAVING COUNT(*) != 5
) AS t1 ON t.IRIG_TIME = t1.IRIG_TIME;
select * from Table1;
```